# Combine Table Results in a Relational Database

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join

OK, first-off let me make this clear : I'm *very* weak with SQL and Databases (I mean apart from several simple statements), but it turns out I have to deal with some **SQLite** DBs, so I guess I need your help on this query (which should be ultra-simple simple for anyone more familiar with SQL than me...):

**I have 2 tables :**

```
TOKENTYPES

TOKENTYPE_ID  TOKENTYPE_NAME
1             nameA
2             nameB
3             nameC

TOKENS

TOKEN_ID TOKENTYPE_ID TOKEN_NAME
1        2            tokA
2        2            tokB
3        3            tokC
```

**What I know :**

- By `SELECT TOKENTYPE_ID,TOKEN_NAME FROM TOKENS`, I can get all (TOKENTYPE_ID,TOKEN_NAME) pairs from TOKENS
- By `SELECT TOKENTYPE_NAME FROM TOKENTYPES WHERE TOKENTYPE_ID=2`, I can get the `Name` for a specific token ID.

Now, here's the catch :

**How** can I sort-of "combine" these 2 queries and get a table with `TOKENTYPE_NAME`, `TOKEN_NAME`?

---

**EDIT:**

**Desired Result :**

```
TOKEN_NAME TOKENTYPE_NAME

tokA       nameB
tokB       nameB
tokC       nameC
```

Comment: can you show you desired result? `:)`

Comment: @JW. Just updated my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tt.TOKENTYPE_NAME, t.TOKEN_NAME 
FROM TOKENS AS t
JOIN TOKENTYPES AS tt
    ON tt.TOKENTYPE_ID = t.TOKENTYPE_ID
```

Comment: Whoa! That was fast. (Took me a bit just to "convert" the example table/field names to the real ones, but it turns out it works great. ) Thanks a lot mate! (I guess I'll have to play with SQL a bit more some day...)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.Token_Name,
        b.TokenType_Name
FROM    Tokens  a
        INNER JOIN TokenTypes b
            ON a.TokenType_ID = b.TokenType_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/046a4/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

RESULT

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╗
║ TOKEN_NAME ║ TOKENTYPE_NAME ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╣
║ tokA       ║ nameB          ║
║ tokB       ║ nameB          ║
║ tokC       ║ nameC          ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! (for the answer *and* the reference you pointed me too). (In order to be fair though, I'll have to accept @JodyT's answer).